# how to round down an address using arithmetic and masks?

Tags: linux-kernel, process, math, macros, stack

I have a pointer `ptr`, which its address is in the kernel stack space.

I want to get to the process descriptor address using this `ptr`.

Since the kernel stack space and the process descriptor size together is 8kb, I know I need to round down the address of `ptr` to get to the address of the process descriptor.

(a block that has the kernel stack and the process descriptor starts with an address number that is a multiplication of 8)

How can I do so in a macro? What mask do I need to use?

Comment: Kernel-mode programming being what it is, a private hand-rolled bodge for just one 32-bit architecture (per the duplicate question) is a maintainability problem waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define MASK 0x01FF

int a = 0;
intptr_t b = (intptr_t)&a;
b &=~MASK;
int * c= (int *)b;
```

inptr_t is a type large enough to hold a pointer, thats why i chose it over the standard integer